# Is it possible to use QgsMapDecoration to enable/disable a copyright decoration?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I'm looking to use pyqgis to enable/disable and set values for different decorations on the map, particularly the copyright statement.

I came across this: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.22/core/QgsMapDecoration.html#qgis.core.QgsMapDecoration and was wondering if anyone knows if it's possible to use it to change the decorations?